# Chat list messages can't scroll up using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make messages shows from bottom to top, like on whatsapp, you will see the latest messages and it will start from bottom and for older messages you need to scroll up.

I'm using `display: flex;` and `justify-content: flex-end;` which seems to display correctly (from bottom).

But the problem is that I can't scroll to top, it does not let me.

How can I fix this?

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.box {
  width: 800px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px 0;
  background: red;
}

.message {
  margin: 10px;
}

.message.player {
  background-color: #ccc
}

.message.me {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="box">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
      <span>Yesterday</span>
    </div>
    <div class="message player">
      <span>Message from friend 1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="message player">
      <span>Message from friend 2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="message player">
      <span>Message from friend 3</span>
    </div>
     <div class="header">
      <span>Today</span>
    </div>
    <div class="message me">
      <span>Message from me 1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="message me">
      <span>Message from me 2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="message me">
      <span>Message from me 3</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a hack how to do it with CSS with `flex-direction: column-reverse` for a wrapper, which I attached as an example. But it probably would be better to make it explicitly with JavaScript using [`Window.scroll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll) method.

```css
.test {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.test:nth-of-type(2n + 1) {
  background: yellow;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="div">
  <div class="test">1</div>
  <div class="test">2</div>
  <div class="test">3</div>
  <div class="test">4</div>
  <div class="test">5</div>
  <div class="test">6</div>
  <div class="test">7</div>
  <div class="test">8</div>
  <div class="test">9</div>
  <div class="test">10</div>
  <div class="test">11</div>
  <div class="test">12</div>
  <div class="test">13</div>
  <div class="test">14</div>
  <div class="test">15</div>
  <div class="test">16</div>
  <div class="test">17</div>
  <div class="test">18</div>
  <div class="test">19</div>
  <div class="test">20</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are forcing your `.container` div to be of fixed height (i.e 100% of its parent). Remove the `height: 100%;` and `overflow-y: auto;` from `.container` and set `overflow-y: auto;` on your `.box` div.

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.box {
  width: 800px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
/*   height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto; */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px 0;
  background: red;
}

.message {
  margin: 10px;
}

.message.player {
  background-color: #ccc
}

.message.me {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

Comment: Well, I can scroll now, but I want the messages to be shown from bottom and to scroll up to top to see older messages, like on whatsapp.